# Create Database backup using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am using this code to create backup but every time I run it, I get result as

```
Couldn't Create the backup!
```

I have read many tutorials.  Most of them have used same code but I don't know what problem is. I am using MySQL and PATH Environment Variable is set.

```
public class Temp {

public void restoreDB(String path){

    String executeCmd = "mysql -u root -proot -B temp1 -r " + path;

    System.out.println(executeCmd);

    Process runtimeProcess;

    try
    {
       runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", executeCmd });

       int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

       System.out.println(processComplete);

       if(processComplete == 0)
       {
          System.out.println("Backup Created Successfully !");
       }
       else
       {
          System.out.println("Couldn't Create the backup !");
       }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }

   }

      public static void main(String[]args){

         new Temp().restoreDB("C:/File.sql");
      }


}
```

Comment: Your post is exceptionally unhelpful. What have you tried so far? Have you tried running that command by hand?

Comment: I tried that,it worked too on mysql command line but through java code i dont know that error it is giving.

Comment: Why? You can schedule the backup directly from within MySQL. No Java required at all.

Comment: @EJP yes I can, but the need is for customer ,if I have developed an application and delivered it ,then the only component with which a customer will interact is java app, and thus if he need to make backup ,then he can do that using java code.
Do you have any idea how to achieve it?